# Create transitions and animations as in spotify

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

How can I creat in my app transitions like this  in spotify where a button while I scroll down moves up until it reaches the top of the view? I’d love to know also how creates view that changes smoothly position and dimension.
Here’s the screenshots from spotify:
[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, is to have the button out of the ScrollView and update it's position in the `scrollViewDidScroll` event. You can implement this event by extending `UIScrollViewDelegate` (or `UITableViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` for `UITableViews` and `UICollectionViews`)

Example:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   let yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
   let newPossition = max(scrollableButtonTopConstraint.constant - yOffset, self.minimumPosition)
   self.scrollableButtonTopConstraint.constant = newPossition
}
```

Here, `minimumPosition` is a constant preventing the button to go higher than it should. You should set it to a value applicable to your situation. Also, don't forget to set the delegate on the scrollview and create an outlet for the `scrollableButtonTopConstraint`.